# #include <sqlite3.h> Not working with GCC - C programming

Tags: gcc, c

I have just started with C programming and am originally a python programmer so please try and not use very advanced words I wont understand much. So when I try using gcc as my compiler as I get an error saying sqlite3.h no such file or directory found. Thats turning out to be a problem for me.

Any help will be appreciated.
**Thank You.**
*The Terminal!*

Answer (score 5):

You will have to install the package `libsqlite3-dev` ([How](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=sqlite3.h) I found it out).

Open a terminal and enter the command

```
sudo apt install libsqlite3-dev
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked next time even i shall checkout the packages first. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey but one more problem, now sqlite3_close function still doesnt work, it says `undefined reference to sqlite3_close`. Please help with this.

Comment: @TheTerminal I don't know about the `sqlite3_close` function. Ask a new question instead (preferably in Stack Overflow instead of Ask Ubuntu). My answer only tells how to get `sqlite3.h` in Ubuntu.

Comment: @TheTerminal you need to *link the library* - the header file only provides function declarations, not definitions